# Как переходить на другую страницу после return?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Когда я выполняю например deleteUser используя линк .../deleteUser/name

то возращаю после этого на "/main". Но возращает оно получаеться всё равно на: /deleteUser

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView createAlbum(@RequestParam("name") String name) throws Exception {
...
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/main");

        return model;
    }
```

не могу никак сделать что бы после этого запроса перенаправило на страницу /main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `return "redirect:/любой/путь";`. Правда, придётся убрать аннотацию `@ResponseBody`.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createAlbum(@RequestParam("name") String name) throws Exception {
        ...
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/main");
        ...
        return "redirect:/любой/путь";
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо мил человек. Я долго не мог понять почесу redirect не работает. Оказалось дело в аннотации